# How can I use a where clause with the sum of two fields

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I need to sum two fields in each record and then if that sum is greater than 0 select the record.
Here's what the model looks like:

```
    class Location(models.Model):
        day1 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        day2 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        day3 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        day4 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        day5 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        day6 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        day7 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

and this is the query I have built

```
Location.objects.extra(select={'fieldsum': 'day1 + day2+ day3+ day4+ day5+ day6+ day7'},where=['fieldsum > 0'])
```

but it throws an error saying

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "fieldsum" does not exist
```

Comment: In django 1.8 it will be possible to use F() in annotate, so `Model.objects.annotate(sum=F('day1')+F('day2')+...+F('day5')).filter(sum__gt=0)` will be possible.

Comment: Also, just to give you a higher-level answer, in general for SQL you would add a condition to an aggregate function in a "HAVING" clause, not a "WHERE" clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need add an extra field, just use [F() Django built-in function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model) and transform

`day1 + day2+ day3+ day4+ day5+ day6+ day7 > 0` to `day1 > 0 - day2 - day3 - day4 - day5 - day6 - day7`

Then, your query should looks like this:

```
Location.objects.filter(day1__gt = 0 - F('day2') - F('day3') ..... -F('day7')  )
```

Comment: sorry I didn't include all the fields... I'm not sure how to do that with all those fields.. thanks for the quick answer though!

Comment: ok I see what you did there some simple algebra lol thank you!

Comment: @TylerRice  np, you can mark as correct answer, if it was helpful.